# i passed the id from view to controller through routes due to it my another view does not getting the js and css files

Tags: php, laravel

Actually I sent my id from view to controller through routes code is given below

```
<a type="button" href="{{url('/booknow')}}/{{$id}}" class="btn btn-default">Book Now</a>
```

it's in view file whose name is the team

```
Route::get('/booknow/{id}', 'BooknowController@show');
```

it's my routes and I am passing id from route to controller and in the controller, I am getting some staff from database using this id but return the data to another partial view called booknow and this booknow view can not accept the  js and css files

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale()}}">

{{-- <html lang="en"> --}}

@include('Partials._head')

<body>
{{-- @include('Partials/_languagePopup') --}}
@include('Partials._nav')
    <!--================ Home Data Access Through Blade =================-->
    {{-- <div class="container"> --}}
       @yield('content')
    {{-- </div> --}}
    <!--================ End Home Data Area=================-->
@include('Partials._footer')

@include('Partials/_javascript')

</body>

</html>
```

It's the main page

```
@extends('main')
@section('content')

<section class="feature-area section_gap_top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-end justify-content-left">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="main_title">
                        <p>We’re Offering these Popular Services</p>
                        <h1>Getting Adventure with Services</h1>
                        <span class="title-widget-bg"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- single-feature -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-feature">
                        <div class="feature-details">
                            <h5>Desert Riding Turning <br>
                                So much Flowery</h5>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecter adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="primary-btn mb-40">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="feature-thumb">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/service/s1.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- single-feature -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-feature">
                        <div class="feature-details">
                            <h5>Relaxation in the <br>
                                Local Beach Campfire</h5>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecter adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="primary-btn mb-40">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="feature-thumb">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/service/s2.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- single-feature -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                    <div class="single-feature">
                        <div class="feature-details">
                            <h5>Forest Exploration <br>
                                with Energy Package</h5>
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consecter adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
                            </p>
                            <a href="#" class="primary-btn mb-40">Read More</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="feature-thumb">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="img/service/s3.png" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

@endsection
```

it's my booknow .blade.php page and till yet I did not send anything here from controller due to css and js files issue

```
public function show($id)
    {
$sellers_id = $id;

        $seller_data = new Seller;
         // dd($sellers_id);
         $seller_name = User::where('id','=', $sellers_id)->pluck('name');
         // dd($seller_name);
         $sellers_data = Seller::where('seller_id','=', $sellers_id)->get();
        return view('Partials.booknow');
}
```

it's the booknow controller and the show function in it right now I'm not returning anything on view

[image: you can see the image]

Comment: Not sure how the `id` parameter is related to assets not showing. Can you post the part where you include/link your css/js files? (edit your question and paste there please)

Comment: @kerbholz okay now check

Answer (score 0):

i did it using `asset()`in files link